# Getting error from sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is the error log i get this error when i try to create a new user when i do:

```
u = User (...)
```

Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/quechon/PycharmProjects/untitled3/myapp/login/routes.py", line 66, in _register_process
timecreated=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
File "<string>", line 4, in __init__

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 414, in _initialize_instance
manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 186, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 411, in _initialize_instance
return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
File "/home/quechon/PycharmProjects/untitled3/myapp/models.py", line 80, in __init__
self.follow(self)
File "/home/quechon/PycharmProjects/untitled3/myapp/models.py", line 47, in follow
if not self.is_following(user):
File "/home/quechon/PycharmProjects/untitled3/myapp/models.py", line 57, in is_following
return self.followed.filter_by(followed_id=user.id).first() is not None
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1517, in filter_by
return self.filter(sql.and_(*clauses))
File "<string>", line 2, in filter

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 198, in generate
self = args[0]._clone()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/dynamic.py", line 278, in _clone
orm_util.instance_str(instance), self.attr.key))
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <User at 0x7fe2ac0e6e80> is not bound to a Session, and no contextual session is established; lazy load operation of attribute 'followed' cannot proceed
```

This is the model:

```
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    password = db.Column(db.Binary)
    profilepic = db.Column(db.String)
    timecreated = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    #picture = db.relationship('Picture', backref='owner', lazy='dynamic')
    comment = db.relationship('Comment', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
    post = db.relationship('Post', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    followed = db.relationship('Follow', foreign_keys=[Follow.follower_id],
                                backref=db.backref('follower', lazy='joined'),
                                lazy='dynamic',
                                cascade='all, delete-orphan')
    followers = db.relationship('Follow',
                                foreign_keys=[Follow.followed_id],
                                backref=db.backref('followed', lazy='joined'),
                                lazy='dynamic',
                                cascade='all, delete-orphan')

    def follow(self, user):
        if not self.is_following(user):
            f = Follow(follower=self, followed=user)
            db.session.add(f)

    def unfollow(self, user):
        f = self.followed.filter_by(followed_id=user.id).first()
        if f:
            db.session.delete(f)

    def is_following(self, user):
        return self.followed.filter_by(followed_id=user.id).first() is not None

    def is_followed_by(self, user):
        return self.followers.filter_by(follower_id=user.id).first() is not None

    @property
    def followed_posts(self):
        return Post.query.join(Follow.followed_id == Post.user_id)\
        .filter(Follow.follower_id == self.id)

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.follow(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<id - {self.id} | - {self.username}>'
```

I would like to know why that happened and how to avoid this error next time

The only thing i found online about was to use  `lazy='subquery'` instead of `lazy='dynamic'` but using that wont allow my query to use filter_by attribute.

Comment: How are you running this? The error `Parent instance <User at 0x7fe2ac0e6e80> is not bound to a Session` suggests you are running it outside of a session

Comment: I did u = User(username='name', ...) from terminal and when i hit enter i get the error or if i try to create from browser when submitting i get the same

Comment: How did you start your Python shell? Did you use `./manage.py shell` or just `python`?

Comment: @Miguel solve the problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to interact with your flask app via the interactive shell. You can do this using the command line interface (CLI).

See docs:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/shell/

Comment: Would you please be more specific on what is not bound to session means of course ill check the link out but just would like a brief explanation if you can please

Comment: @quechon, typically when you access a web page it keeps track of you (and each user) using a session. You can think of this as a way for the server to track what multiple users are doing at once. Importantly it also tracks who is doing what, for example you may not want anyone to be able create a new user by running  `u = User (...)`

Comment: thats understandable but what i really want is for the user to create a new account dont really get how to stop that from happening and sorry if im giving you hard time understanding thanks